# Sort() returns an out of order array

Tags: php

I have an array that is populated from the function [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php). After I sort it (tried `asort()`, `ksort()` and `rsort()` and all of them show the same result: an out of order array...

This is my code.

```
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($location, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$file_paths = iterator_to_array( $fi, false);
rsort($file_paths);
echo "<pre>", print_r($file_paths), "</pre>";
```

The `print_r` returns:

```
Array
(
[0] => SplFileInfo Object
    (
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/majo/log_files/teste/log2014324.txt
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => log2014324.txt
    )

[1] => SplFileInfo Object
    (
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/majo/log_files/teste/log2014325.txt
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => log2014325.txt
    )

[2] => SplFileInfo Object
    (
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/majo/log_files/teste/log2014323.txt
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => log2014323.txt
    )

[3] => SplFileInfo Object
    (
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/majo/log_files/teste/log2014322.txt
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => log2014322.txt
    )

)
```

After a routine to clear the name of the file I get this output:

```
2014324.txt
2014325.txt
2014323.txt
2014322.txt
```

However because of `rsort()` (the function used at that time) it should be:

```
2014325.txt
2014324.txt
2014323.txt
2014322.txt
```

Everytime the `2014325.txt` is out of place and I can't seem to get it in place, does anyone know how to fix this?

I can implement a solution that involves doing the sorting in a manual way, but it will spend a lot more time and resources, however.

PS: `ksort()` output:

```
2014322.txt
2014323.txt
2014325.txt
2014324.txt
```

Comment: You are trying to sort object when you haven't even checked for their values. Maybe this http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.asort.php will help you in getting what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterator_to_array` gives you an array of objects, but php has no clue how to compare them. You have to extract the sort key (e.g. a path) and tell php to sort by this key, for example:

```
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($location, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$file_paths = array();
foreach($fi as $f)
    $file_paths[$f->getRealPath()] = $f;
ksort($file_paths);
```

If you only need file paths and not interested in additional data `SplFileInfo` provides, then [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) might be a simpler option:

```
$file_paths = glob("$location/*");
```

Note that the `glob` output is already sorted.

Comment: The [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) works!!! It was as simple as you pointed. Cheers.

Comment: Nice and elegant solution to the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting the first level of the array (the objects without content). The second level of the array (so to speak... actually the contents of the object) contain the values you want to sort.

You will need to create a different method which sorts it correctly for you.

Comment: Thanks, I understood why my code was not working. Still getting used to this kind of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Use [usort function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function my_sort_function($a,$b){
   if ($a->{fileName:SplFileInfo:private} == $b->{fileName:SplFileInfo:private}){
      return 0;
   }
   return ($a->{fileName:SplFileInfo:private} > $b->{fileName:SplFileInfo:private})?1:-1;
}
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($location, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$file_paths = iterator_to_array( $fi, false);
usort($file_paths,'my_sort_function');
echo "<pre>", print_r($file_paths), "</pre>";
```

I'm not sure how to access the property of you model but I hope this works

Comment: I've looked at [usort](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) as well, but I don't really get how the whole `my_sort_function` (is this case) works. How do `$a` and `$b` get their values?

Comment: $a and $b are one of the values of the array you want to sort. In your case they are the object you have inside. You treat them like every item in the array has the same structure (if not you have to add more logic to the function I wrote)

Comment: I feel it's a like to confusing using [usort](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). I think I will turn to the `glob`. But thanks anyway.